# OpenMP: why #pragma openmp parallel should be useful without for?

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm an OpenMP beginner and [from what I've read](http://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/#ParallelConstruct) `#pragma omp parallel`:

> It creates a team of N threads ..., all of which execute the next
>   statement ... After the statement, the threads join back into one.

I cannot imagine an example where this could be useful without the `for` keyword after the directive written above. What I mean is that the `for` keyword split the iterations between the threads of the team, while with the directive above the following block/statement will be executed by all the threads and there is no performance improvement. Can you help me please to clarify it?

Comment: Look at OpenMP tasks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide your own mechanism that splits the job into parallel pieces, but relies on OpenMP for parallelism.

Here’s a hypothetic example that uses OpenMP to dequeue some operations and run then in parallel:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    operation op;
    while( queue.tryDequeue( &op ) )
        op.run();
}
```

The implementation of `queue.tryDequeue` must be thread-safe, i.e. guarded by critical section/mutex, or lock-free implementation.

To be efficient, the implementation of `op.run()` must be CPU-heavy, taking much longer than `queue.tryDequeue()` Otherwise, you’ll spend most of the time blocking that queue, and not doing the parallelizable work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please give a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38198491/openmp-should-i-use-critical-or-atomic) question please?

Answer (score 0):

The for keyword does not divide the work !!!

You have to remember that divide the work means each thread executes a section of your loop. If you insist on using #pragma omp parallel then its like this

```
#pragma omp parallel
{ 
   #pragma omp for
   for(int i= 1...100)
   {
   }
}
```

what the above code does is divides the for loop among n threads and for each for n threads anything declared inside the #pragma omp for is a private variable to that thread. This ensure thread safety and also means you are responsible for gathering data, eg using reduction operations

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please give a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38198491/openmp-should-i-use-critical-or-atomic) question please?